# Force compiler to use static definition from a specific C file

Tags: c, compilation, declaration

Two C files have the same variable name declared differently.

Can I force the compiler (Visual Studio or gcc) to prefer one declaration over the other?

The scenario is that I have a C file where I would not like to change anything and my own C file with several overlapping definitions, and that's where I would like to make my changes.

For example, I have the following definition in the original c file :

`static unsigned char key[27 + 1] = "<put ur key here>";`

And I have the following definition in my own c file :

`static unsigned char key[27 + 1] = "abcde...";`

When compiling, I would like the compiler to use my declaration instead of the original cpp file.

Comment: A `static` variable definition can only be used in the source file where it is defined.  It doesn't matter if the same name is used in other files — the static variable can't cause confusion.  So, your scenario doesn't make a lot of sense yet.  Please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  This will demonstrate what you mean and where you are having problems.

Comment: If you have a file you don't want to change and your own C file, then change the name in your C file.  What is the problem there?  Are there any headers involved that are causing chaos?

Comment: The incentive is to use the definition in my own file rather than the original c code file.

Comment: Please clarify, who should use the definition, and why renaming is not an option. (Even if renaming is not necessary, as Jonathan pointed out.) We are waiting for your [mre].

Comment: Well, when I compile the c file, an essembly efi file is created. I would like the compiled efi file to use my definition as the example Ive provided. As for the original cpp file, I woulld not like to change it because it gets a lot of updates and I use automation to compile it, so I would not like to use regex and replace the definitions prior to each compilation. Hope that it clarify my question. Thank you

Comment: Static is not global.

Comment: If your var is global then reset the value at the beginning your main procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72149662/force-compiler-to-use-static-definition-from-a-specific-c-file#comment127480359_72149662) whether you have a C++ file as the original code that you are (not unreasonably) reluctant to change.  I'm going to assume it is a C file, not a C++ file.  It doesn't make a lot of difference except to the file name you create.

As pointed out in the comments, you cannot achieve that which appears to be your goal by defining a different static variable in a different source file.

The static variable `key` defined in `own.c` is wholly unrelated to the static variable `key` defined in `original.c`.  You cannot make them equivalent.  If the `original.c` code does not provide a mechanism to change the value in its `key`, you are hosed until you change the code to provide such a mechanism.

One gruesome but effective way is to create a source file `wrapper.c` along these lines:

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include "original.c"
void set_original_key(const char *new_key)
{
    if (strlen(new_key) < sizeof(key))
        strcpy(key, new_key);
}
```

and a header file `wrapper.h` which contains a declaration of `set_original_key()`:

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H_INCLUDED
#define WRAPPER_H_INCLUDED

extern void set_original_key(const char *key);

#endif /* WRAPPER_H_INCLUDED */
```

Then compile `wrapper.c` to `wrapper.o` and link that into your executable instead of `original.o` (which you used to use).  And include `wrapper.h` in the code that needs to set the key and call `set_original_key()` to change the key to the value of your choosing.

This subterfuge effectively adds code to the `original.c` file without altering it.  The extra code has access to the variables in the original file, including the file-scope static variables.

The function shown doesn't report an error when the new key is too long to fit into the space for the key defined in `original.c`.  It could easily be revised to return zero on success and -1 on failure.  Note that it is fortuitous but extremely convenient that `original.c` does not define `key` as a constant (as it should).  If the data to be changed was in fact constant (or if the key was hidden in a function instead of being defined at file scope), you'd be stuck!

Comment: Thank you, will defiantly try that !
Also, I read that preprocessor code in h file could do the trick ? Would that still require a wrapper.c file ?